# I need to create an accessor method that will return the last number that was crossed off

Tags: java

My java assignment consists of creating a board game called Qwixx. You roll a dice and cross out the number on your gameboard where there are 2 rows going from 2-12 and 2 other rows going from 12-2. My problem here is creating the accessor method to get the last crossed off number for each row. The last crossed off number should be the farthest to the right of the gameboard. This is what I have for the Player class:

```
public class Player {
    private String[][] gameBoard = new String[4][11];
    private int lastCrossedOffR;

    //default constuctor 
    public Player() {
        lastCrossedOffR = 0;
        initializeGameboard();
    }

    //get method to obtain the last number that has been crossed off
    public int getLastCrossedOffR() {
        for(int j = 0; j<gameBoard[0].length;) {
            if (gameBoard[0][j] == "X") {
                if (j == 0)
                    lastCrossedOffR = 2;
                else if (j == 1)
                    lastCrossedOffR = 3;
                else if (j == 2)
                    lastCrossedOffR = 4;
                else if (j == 3)
                    lastCrossedOffR = 5;
                else if (j == 4)
                    lastCrossedOffR = 6;
                else if (j == 5)
                    lastCrossedOffR = 7;
                else if (j == 6)
                    lastCrossedOffR = 8;
                else if (j == 7)
                    lastCrossedOffR = 9;
                else if (j == 8)
                    lastCrossedOffR = 10;
                else if (j == 9)
                    lastCrossedOffR = 11;
                else if (j == 10)
                    lastCrossedOffR = 12;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
        return lastCrossedOffR;
    }

    //method that initializes each row of the game board 
    public void initializeGameboard() {
        for (int i = 0; i<gameBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<gameBoard[i].length; j++) {
                if (i==0 || i==1) {
                    if (j==0) {gameBoard[i][j] = "2";} 
                    else if (j==1) {gameBoard[i][j] = "3";} 
                    else if (j==2) {gameBoard[i][j] = "X";} //i placed random x's to 
                    else if (j==3) {gameBoard[i][j] = "5";} //test out the get 
                    else if (j==4) {gameBoard[i][j] = "6";} //method
                    else if (j==5) {gameBoard[i][j] = "7";} 
                    else if (j==6) {gameBoard[i][j] = "X";} 
                    else if (j==7) {gameBoard[i][j] = "X";} //in my case, what the
                    else if (j==8) {gameBoard[i][j] = "10";} //get method should 
                    else if (j==9) {gameBoard[i][j] = "11";} //return is: 9
                    else if (j==10) {gameBoard[i][j] = "12";}

                } else if (i==2 || i==3) {
                    if (j==0) {gameBoard[i][j] = "12";} 
                    else if (j==1) {gameBoard[i][j] = "11";} 
                    else if (j==2) {gameBoard[i][j] = "10";} 
                    else if (j==3) {gameBoard[i][j] = "9";} 
                    else if (j==4) {gameBoard[i][j] = "8";} 
                    else if (j==5) {gameBoard[i][j] = "7";} 
                    else if (j==6) {gameBoard[i][j] = "6";} 
                    else if (j==7) {gameBoard[i][j] = "5";} 
                    else if (j==8) {gameBoard[i][j] = "4";} 
                    else if (j==9) {gameBoard[i][j] = "3";} 
                    else if (j==10) {gameBoard[i][j] = "2";}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my Driver class:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player obj1 = new Player();
        obj1.printGameboard(); //assume this method is already created in the Player class
        System.out.print("The last crossed off number for the Red row is: " + obj1.getLastCrossedOffR());
    }
}
```

This is what needs to be displayed when I run the code:

```
player's gameboard: 
           Red: 1 2 3 X 5 6 7 X X 10 11 12
        Yellow: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
         Green: 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
          Blue: 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

The last crossed off number for the Red row is: 9
```

Please help me figure out how to fix my `getLastCrossedOffR()` method! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please fix your code formatting first, your `getLastCrossedOffR()` method has three opening brackets but only one closing. This code would not compile.

Comment: Oh, thank you for pointing that out! I corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to compare `String`s with `==` rather than `equals`, use this instead:

```
public int getLastCrossedOffR() {
    for(int j = 0; j < gameBoard[0].length;) {
        // was previously `gameBoard[0][j] == "X"`
        if ("X".equals(gameBoard[0][j])) {
            // ...
```

The `==` operator compares what is **literally** in the variables. For primitives like `int`s this is fine since it literally stores the primitive values. But in the case of `Object`s like `String`s it stores the object reference.

Imagine that `"X"` is a `String` with the reference `Object #1` and `gameBoard[0][0]` stores the `String` reference `Object #2`.

Calling `"X" == gameBoard[0][0]` would be like calling `Object #1 == Object #2` which is false. (unless you had stored `Object #1` in `gameBoard[0][0]`)

But calling `"X".equals(gameBoard[0][0])` would be like calling `Object #1.equals(Object #2)` which goes into the `equals` function of `Object #1` (aka `String.equals(Object o)`) and compares the *values* of those two `String`s rather than comparing their references.

**The rule of thumb is that `==` only works for primitives (`int`, `float`, `long`, `double`, `short`, `byte`, `char`, `boolean`), but use `.equals` (might have to be overriden) for everything else.**

Comment: Ah yes I have not considered the equals() method since I am comparing two Strings... Thank you so much, the accessor method now works!